# Linux swapping too much

Tags: linux, memory, swap

My Linux (Mint 17.2) computer has 4 GB of RAM and 8 GB of swap partition. I have swappiness set to 10 instead of default 60 and it works perfectly, sadly only for some time from start up.

When I start computer and it after a while comes to that the RAM is used by 90 % or so, it starts to swap -- perfect. However, after a few days (if no restart was performed, only sleep) it seems that the computer starts to completely ignore the swappiness setting and the RAM is used only by 50 % and the swap is used by almost the same amount of bytes. In other words, once used, the swap keeps to be filled even there is plenty of space in the RAM again.

I cannot set the swap off -- KDE/Chrome are little hungry. Can I somehow tell the computer not to use the swap, when there is available space in the RAM again?

**Edit**

requested information (at the time of adding it, the situation is a little bit better, it is not unusual to have 0.5 GB less in RAM and more in Swap):

cat /proc/meminfo

```
MemTotal:        3902076 kB
MemFree:          424196 kB
Buffers:           21048 kB
Cached:           885268 kB
SwapCached:       320476 kB
Active:          1548768 kB
Inactive:        1093232 kB
Active(anon):    1193844 kB
Inactive(anon):   794352 kB
Active(file):     354924 kB
Inactive(file):   298880 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       8388604 kB
SwapFree:        6881408 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1599236 kB
Mapped:           302260 kB
Shmem:            252504 kB
Slab:             351700 kB
SReclaimable:      89904 kB
SUnreclaim:       261796 kB
KernelStack:        6400 kB
PageTables:        58436 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    10339640 kB
Committed_AS:    9101152 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      295192 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359426556 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    141312 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB                                                                                    
DirectMap4k:      345920 kB                                                                                    
DirectMap2M:     3700736 kB
```

free

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached                                      
Mem:       3902076    3539808     362268     255428      28264     899880                                      
-/+ buffers/cache:    2611664    1290412                                                                       
Swap:      8388604    1489808    6898796
```

df -h

```
Souborový systém Velikost Užito Volno Uži% Připojeno do                                                        
udev                 1,9G  4,0K  1,9G   1% /dev                                                                
tmpfs                382M  1,5M  380M   1% /run                                                                
/dev/sda4             30G   18G   11G  63% /
none                 4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                 5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                 1,9G  214M  1,7G  12% /run/shm
none                 100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda5             30G   16G   13G  56% /home
/dev/sda6            333G  283G   34G  90% /media/ales/data
/dev/sda2            283M   47M  221M  18% /boot
```

ps -eo pid,rss,size,vsize,comm | sort -rn -k 3 | head -20

```
 2547 111956 2772540 3682812 plasma-desktop
 5173  5456 2634668 2670468 Lexicon.exe
 2635 35084 2524912 2889496 dropbox
 2527 47800 2418208 3208048 kwin
 1044   696 2052944 2102624 console-kit-dae
 5147   472 1935412 2044512 winedevice.exe
 5143    44 1869064 1918760 services.exe
 2567  9092 1867348 1906024 mysqld
 2563  5560 1844548 2079388 akonadiserver
 5156    36 1803524 1850984 plugplay.exe
 5163   916 1739940 1858608 explorer.exe
 3997 195952 1373016 1729604 chrome
30458 264260 835336 1207720 chrome
 2598 40524 828932 1665280 krunner
 2314 22084 754576 1553696 kded4
 1886 105908 689432 857012 savscand
 6847 225704 675248 1172204 chrome
30464 126884 642152 992096 chrome
 9050 130264 632096 808100 savscand
30106 172300 582836 1461732 chrome
```

Comment: Please add `cat /proc/meminfo`, `free`, `df -h` and ` ps -eo pid,rss,size,vsize,comm | sort -rn -k 3 | head -20` output to your question.

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you for suggesting the commands, I have added the output.

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be a memory leak in either chrome or one of your kde applications. Identify which one it is and restart it.

Another possibility might be a tmpfs based file system (likely /tmp) filling up. In that case remove or empty unused files there.

---

Edit:
 The statistics added to your question do not show anything symptomatic.

In the past, the OS swapped out pages while being shot in RAM but this situation is over and there is no more RAM pressure. Whatever the swappiness setting, the OS is not going to swap in (disk to RAM) pages if no running process is reclaiming them. The active memory largely fit in the available RAM size so there should be no performance hit despite the swap area not being empty.

Comment: /tmp seems to be almost empty and I am not sure what do you mean by the memory leak, however, all applications seem to divide their memory into x % into RAM and (100-x) % into swap, with very similar x for all of them; hence, it seems to me that this is not the case, is it?